# VS SSDT project - Compare Azure & on-premises database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools

Recently we have decided to move our old stuff from SQL Server 2012 to Azure SQL server.  I have created a SSDT project using 'Import->Database' option and deployed existing database from SQL Server 2012 to Azure Database.

For some reason we must continue to use existing 'SQL Server 2012' database, so our DBA is changing schema on 'SQL Server 2012' database for new business features.  In order to make sure that both the schema ( SQL Server 2012 and Azure SQL Server ) I am planning to use 'Schema compare' option.  My source is on-premises 'SQL Server 2012' database and destination is 'Azure SQL Server' database.

After finishing comparison I am getting below error.

"A project which specifies SQL Server 2012 as the target platform cannot be published to SQL Azure."

Is there any way for comparing on-premises database with SQL Azure and push changes to Azure db suing SSDT ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Schema Compare window, click the Options button, go to General, and select "Allow incompatible platforms". This will allow you to compare different platforms such as this. Similarly when publishing you can select this in the Advanced publish options.

I would actually recommend setting the target platform for your database project as Azure rather than SQL 2012, as it enforces a more restrictive set of rules than SQL 2012 does at present. You should be able to deploy anything built with Azure validation to SQL 2012, but the same isn't true the other way around. The same "Allow incompatible platforms" setting will work that way too.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It worked for me.  Actually target platform for my database project is SQL Azure only.  But we are planning to release product on Azure platform after 6 months time.  So while adding new features we have to add it to our existing server i.e. SQL Server 2012.  Side by side I am making sure that my Azure database schema remains in sink with our existing production database schema.  Is there any better way to do this?